# How do I target champions instead of minions?

Tags: league-of-legends

How do I avoid healing minions or using Soraka's "Infuse" on minions instead of my teammate, when the minions/champions are clustered ?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to do so is pressing your spell and clicking (depending if you have smartcast on or not) on your target's portrait in the top left corner of the screen.  This is extremely useful when playing a champion with clutch target abilities during clustered teamfights such as Shen and Soraka.

The tilde ~ character is incredibly awkward to press if your abilities are binded to QWER, while clicking on the portrait requires nothing but a normal mouse click/hover.

Answer (score 1):

Simple: hold the ~ key and you will only be able to target champions with your abilities and attacks.

Answer (score 1):

You could cycle through minion hp bars with the "L" key. Basically the idea would be to turn off minion hp bars when entering a fight. As support, you really wouldn't need to see them at all and could leave them off.

This won't stop you from targeting a minion, but should help with clearing clutter on the screen.

The "~" key is new to me, i'll have to try it.